# How to test bytes.ErrTooLarge panic error

Tags: unit-testing, go

I want to simulate bytes.ErrTooLarge panic error on bytes.Buffer.Write method and test panic handling. I have tried to write unlimited data amount to exceed memory but then whole test crashed. What are the other options?

Comment: When you encounter this specific error in your program (not the tests) what action do you take?

Comment: Panic can happen in package that is using bytes.Buffer . Package is handling this panic and transforming panic to normal error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like a job for a mock object. Use this (badBuffer) in place of your bytes.Buffer during your test.

```
type badBuffer bytes.Buffer

func (b *badBuffer) Write(p []byte) (n int, err error) {
    panic(bytes.ErrTooLarge)
}
```

Comment: A nitpick: it's not a mock, [it's a stub](https://martinfowler.com/articles/mocksArentStubs.html).